# unidirectional OneToMany mapping problems

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm facing some problems with unidirectional onetomany mapping. 
I got tables Users and Rubrica:

```
User (
scode double precision NOT NULL,
...
CONSTRAINT utenti_pkey PRIMARY KEY (scode)
)

Rubrica (
id serial NOT NULL,
id_owner integer NOT NULL,
id_contact integer NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT rubrica_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id ),
CONSTRAINT rubrica_fk01 FOREIGN KEY (id_owner)
  REFERENCES users (scode) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT rubrica_fk02 FOREIGN KEY (id_contact)
  REFERENCES users (scode) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Don't mind about Users double PKey. It's a customer's table and I can't modify it. Rubrica store relation between its owner, a User, and contacts, a set of User too.
User is mapped as follow:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "utenti", schema = "public")
public class User implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "scode", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Integer scode;
...
}
```

Ok. Here is when problems come. If I map Rubrica like this:

```
public class Rubrica2 implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_owner", nullable = false, unique = true, referencedColumnName = "scode")
  private User owner;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_contact", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = true, referencedColumnName = "scode")
  private Set<User> relations = new HashSet<User>();
  ...
}
```

JBoss gave me this exception at deploy:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: scode in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(public.rubrica) and its related
```

supertables and secondary tables

If I map Rubrica this way:

```
public class Rubrica2 implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_owner", nullable = false, unique = true, referencedColumnName = "scode")
  private User owner;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "scode")
  private Set<User> relations = new HashSet<User>();
  ...
}
```

I got bad behavior at runtime. If I run this code

```
r = new Rubrica2();
q2.setParameter("id", ownerID);
User owner = (User) q2.getSingleResult();
r.setOwner(owner);
q2.setParameter("id", contactID);
User u = (User) q2.getSingleResult();
r.getRelations().add(u);
entityManager.persist(r);
```

I got this exception:

```
Hibernate: insert into public.rubrica (id_owner) values (?)
11:08:19,440 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 7) 
  ERROR: null values in column "id_contact" violates not-null constraint [n/a]: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
    ERROR: null values in column "id_contact" violates not-null constraint
```

I follow theory indicated [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Undirectional_OneToMany.2C_No_Inverse_ManyToOne.2C_No_Join_Table_.28JPA_2.0_ONLY.29) about onetomany unidirectional.
I'm using JPA2.0, Hibernate4 (as provided by JBoss7.1.1.Final) and PostgresSQL.

Comment: Is Class name Utente is User?

Comment: @Gayathri yes it is. Updated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mapping, or the database design, makes no sense. If you want one Rubrica to have many contacts, you can't have a foreign key to the relation in the rubrica table. A foreign key can only reference **one** contact, not many.

To map such a one-to-many association, you would need a foreign key in user to rubrica (all the users having the same rubrica_id would be the contacts of this rubrica), or a join table between both tables.

Comment: Help me to understand. Why did you say "makes no sense ... A foreign key can only reference one contact, not many"? Users won't mind if they are referred in a Rubrica entry. Rubrica.id_contact refer to User.scode, a row in Rubrica refer just to a User as contact. What's wrong? I think this case was pretty similar to the Employee - Phone example in the link I post, doesn't it?

Comment: You want each rubrica to have *several* contacts. And you try to map this using a user ID in the rubrica table. So each row of the rubrica table, representing one instance of a Rubrica, will refer to *one* contact. How could you refer to *several* users using *one* user ID?

Comment: Ok. So the whole stuff won't work because entity Rubrica can't both encapsulate the Set and have a foreing key. In the Employee-Phone example, Phone has a foreign key to Employee not mapped in its entity. I can't change User table, I must use a jointable. Did I get it?

Comment: No, you didn't. In the user-phone example; user has a OneToMany with Phone. And it's mapped by a foreign key in the **phone** table (i.e. the table of the **many** side of the association). In your code, Rubrica has a OneToMany with User. But instead of mapping it with a foreign key in the user table (which is the many side of the association), you're trying to map it with a foreign key in the rubrica table (which is the **one** side of the association). That doesn't make sense. If a rubrica has many users, the foreign key needs to be in the user table.